# Sql Server: Alternatives for conditional expressions in where condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

By writing client server applications typically one stumbles in cases where he needs to do a query that returns different records according to which is the logged in user.

I use this approach, but I wonder if there are alternatives, may you suggest?

(the reason I ask is that for more complx queries this becomes quite unreadable, while with some `CASE` statements it would be better).

```
declare @UserIsAdministrator bit;
declare @UserID integer; 
set @UserIsAdministrator = 0 -- test value 
set @UserID = 41;            -- test value 

SELECT * FROM employees  
WHERE 
    (@UserIsAdministrator = 1) -- if user is admin return all records
  OR 
    (
       (@UserIsAdministrator = 0) 
     AND 
       (manager_ID = @UserID)
    )                          -- if user is not admin return only "his" records
```

Comment: Well, you can simplify that one specifically like: `WHERE (@manager_ID = @userID OR @UserIsAdministrator = 1)`... But if it's getting too complicated, I'd go with Simen's suggestion of separate queries. You'll often find that queries like this evolve to select different values from the tables depending on the role, too, and quickly you find that you're really trying to write two queries as if they were one query, which is hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

IF and ELSE

```
IF @UserIsAdministrator = 1
    SELECT * FROM employees
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM employees WHERE manager_ID = @UserID
```

Change parameters based on another parameter

```
IF @UserIsAdministrator = 1
    SET @UserID = NULL

SELECT * FROM employees  
WHERE manager_ID = ISNULL(@UserID,  manager_ID)
```

Or different views/stored procs

Comment: Thanks, I choose this as answer since it answer my question, even if as discussed in Simen S answer it can be a nightmare to do things in this way. But when dealing with legacy apps you cannot rewrite the architecture from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would try to avoid embedding this type of authorization within the SQL queries altogether. Have separate queries, and resolve roles and privileges in a separate layer/component before you select which query to execute.

Comment: Ok so probably it is up to one's judgement according on how much complex things are going. Thanks.

Comment: If there is direct database access then any client security can be bypassed. This is one example. Data security arguably should be in the database layer quite often for things like this

Comment: But when things go really fine grained it is a very complex to manage it in the DB layer.